# True False Quiz Function in Python

Tags: python

I have created the following program in Python:

```
def tf_quiz(question, correct_ans):
    if input(question) == correct_ans:
        return("correct")
    else:
        return("incorrect")

quiz_eval = tf_quiz("Birds can fly", "T")

print("your answer is", quiz_eval)
```

However, my output is as following:

```
Birds can flyF
your answer is incorrect
```

But I want the following output:

```
(T/F) Birds can fly: F
your answer is incorrect
```

What do I need to change in my code?

Comment: `quiz_eval = tf_quiz("(T/F) Birds can fly: ", "T")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing a "(T/F) " string at the beginning, and a colon and space at the end.

```
def tf_quiz(question, correct_ans):
    if input("(T/F) " + question + ": ") == correct_ans:
        return("correct")
    else:
        return("incorrect")

quiz_eval = tf_quiz("Birds can fly", "T")

print("your answer is", quiz_eval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either update the question text to have the exact formatting you want:

```
quiz_eval = tf_quiz("(T/F) Birds can fly: ", "T")
```

Or update the `input()` call to insert generic formatting for a true/false question:

```
if input("(T/F) %s: " % question) == correct_ans:
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if input(question) == correct_ans:
```

to:

```
if input(f"(T/F) {question}: ") == correct_ans
```

if you want the caller to be able to specify each question without the extra formatting pieces.